# creating a toolbar or tabBar button with 3 states at bottom

Tags: ios, toolbar, tabbar

I have a scenario, I don't know how to do this..

I am able to set two states of button using `UITabbar`

I need to show a `UIButton` in `UIToolbar` or `UITabbar` button at the bottom of the screen like in **Apple Maps** home screen. it shows 3 states of button, 
how can i achieve such button states. [image: appleMaps]

(At the very left Bottom)

Comment: Can you please post a picture here?

Comment: updated please check

Comment: I think, that will create by just doing image change and save state. and yes, you also need some animation nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually handle the selection states.For example

```
let state = 0
@IBAction func btnClick(sender: AnyObject)
{
   if state == 0
   { 
     state++
     //set corresponding image for button
     //do the first action
    }
    else if state == 1
    { 
      state++
      //set corresponding image for button
      //do the second action
    }
    if state == 2
    { 
      state = 0
      //set corresponding image for button
      //do the third action
    }

  }
```